# AWSSecretsManagerException: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-secrets-manager

I made an implementation of the aws-secretsmanager-jdbc library on a spring boot application like the one presented in this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIbr6-AR6T8)

After following the instructions I was struggling with these two issues:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.sql.DataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.model.AWSSecretsManagerException: The security token included in the request is invalid. (Service: AWSSecretsManager; Status Code: 400; Error Code: UnrecognizedClientException; Request ID: 4880ebc0-59ed-49e6-abc5-6ba535e942eb; Proxy: null)
```

```
com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details. (Service: AWSSecretsManager; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidSignatureException; Request ID: 9a356a2b-b8fe-4810-ae28-08b1b9ec939d)
```

I googled a lot, and I finally came across with the solution:

- For the first issue, I was missing to set the AWS credential enviorment variables: AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY and AWS_DEFAULT_REGION. The spring boot application need these variables in order to connect to AWS.
- For the last issue, after reading this [site](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/aws-cli-signature-does-not-match) I realized that the issue was related to set the correct encoding. So, I tried to run the application in this way:

```
java -jar app.jar -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

And It starts working properly. My code is available [here](https://github.com/danielcasique/aws-secret-manager) in case if you want to take a look.

[Here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000642260-Encoding-of-Spring-Boot-properties-decription-shown-in-IDE) you can find a way to set the encoding on IntelliJ.

Important notes:

- This is not a question. I just want to add some knowledge based on what I was googling without finding any possible solution.
- I sent an email to Maciej who kindly replied and gave some suggestions.

Comment: Are you using an Java SDK provided by AWS?

Comment: nope, just the dependencies as they are set in pom.xml (https://github.com/danielcasique/aws-secret-manager/blob/main/pom.xml). I'll take a look at Java SDK provided by AWS.

Comment: @smac2020 it's just an example that I followed to start using aws secrets manager on spring. It could there are more...

Comment: I am checking on that example. It does not appear to be an Official Java AWS SDK.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Also @maciejwalkowiak said so. Actually, Maciej said "the library itself is not actively maintained by AWS". Anyway, I would appreciate if you have any example over there using aws secrets manager on spring boot application.

Comment: We have Java V2 examples of using AWS Secrets Manager and many other examples of using V2 Java API in a Spring BOOT app that uses a MVC approach.

Answer (score 0):

To invoke **AWS Secrets Manager** from a Spring BOOT app, then best practice is to use the **AWS SDK for Java V2** API. There are many code examples of how to use this API here:

https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/main/javav2/example_code/secretsmanager

And you are correct, you need to use your credentials when using any SDK that AWS supports.

You can use the **AWS SDK for Java** V2 in a Spring Boot project. To see an example that uses Amazon S3 and Amazon Rekognition as an example, see this topic in the Amazon Rekognition Service Guide:

[Detect objects in images with Amazon Rekognition using an AWS SDK](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/example_cross_RekognitionPhotoAnalyzer_section.html)

**Update**
Just tested this Spring BOOT app which works perfectly. Once you understand how to hook into **AWS SDK Java V2** from within a Spring Boot project, then you can work with other services.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I applied the changes to use AWS SDK Java V2 and it works perfectly. [Here](https://github.com/danielcasique/aws-secrets-manager-v3) is my code. BTW, I don't have to set the encoding, It ran with no issues.

Comment: I am glad to hear you got it working

Answer (score 0):

i review the video looks like an interesting approach, however the time has pass and now a days there is **awsspring** framework that have **spring-cloud-starter-aws-secrets-manager-config** dependency which handle this out of the box.

there is working sample on documentation: https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws/tree/main/spring-cloud-aws-samples/spring-cloud-aws-parameter-store-sample

and here you could find a db working too: https://github.com/nekperu15739/aws-secrets-manager